# Local substitution of a native assembly used by a .NetCoreApp project

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core, .net-assembly

I'm trying to discover how to get a .NetCoreApp test project to reference a local native assembly in preference to the same assembly in the packages folder.

I'm using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite in a .NetStandard 1.6 library project, with a requirement to access databases encrypted using RSA which is barely supported.  The library will be consumed by a .Net Framework 4.7 WinForms executable and a .NetCoreApp website.

I can make this work in .Net Framework by adding the nuget packages "Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core""SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3"; copying x86\SQLite.Interop.dll to x86\e_sqlite3.dll in the bin folder, and calling Batteries.Init().

For .NetCoreApp I copy x86\SQLite.Interop.dll to runtimes\win7-x86\native\e_sqlite3.dll, but this assembly is only referenced if I delete the matching version from .nuget\packages\sqlitepclraw.lib.e_sqlite3.v110_xp\1.1.5\runtimes\win7-x86\native.

Does anyone know how I can make it use the local assembly in preference to the assembly from the packages folder?

Answer (score 0):

We've resolved this by adding the library to nuget which was always the destination.  I prefer to do initial development of a library with direct references.

I would prefer to have a better understanding of how native assemblies are discovered, but this is a corner case.

Comment: Can you share the format of the nuget package you used to get this to work?  I am trying to package a .net standard library that has a win-x86 unmanaged dll and include the unmanaged dll when it gets added to the target project.

Comment: I've posted a more detailed answer above.  I probably should have looked up how to use stack overflow :-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to forgive me, I haven't looked at this problem in about 18 months, but the nuspec file is as below.  It took some time to get the targets right so that this would function for both .Net Framework and .Net Core.  This would obviously only work on Windows.

```
<package>
    <metadata>
            <id>$id$</id>
            <version>$version$</version>
            <authors>$authors$</authors>
            <owners>$authors$</owners>
            <description>$description$</description>
            <id>MyCompany.SqlLite.Portable</id>
            <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <dependencies>
            <group targetFramework=".NETStandard1.6">
                <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
                <dependency id="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3" version="1.1.5" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
                <dependency id="System.ServiceModel.Http" version="4.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
                <dependency id="System.ServiceModel.Security" version="4.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
            </group>
        </dependencies>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="$output$\**\*.dll" target="lib\" />

        <file src="x64\SQLite.Interop.dll" target="content\x64\e_sqlite3.dll"/>
        <file src="x86\SQLite.Interop.dll" target="content\x86\e_sqlite3.dll"/>

        <file src="x64\SQLite.Interop.dll" target="runtimes\win7-x64\native\e_sqlite3.dll"/>
        <file src="x86\SQLite.Interop.dll" target="runtimes\win7-x86\native\e_sqlite3.dll"/>
    </files>
</package>
```